# Display form WPQ number assignment

Tags: 2013, web-part, custom-form, form

Does anyone know how the assignment of the WPQ numbers can be changed?

Example: We have a custom new web form with two web parts "ContentEditorWebPart" and a "ListFormWebPart".  When the aspx page is rendered, the ContentEditorWebPart is assigned WPQ2 and the ListFormWebPart is assigned WPQ1.

Note: We have another custom web form that has the opposite assignments - the ContentEditorWebPart is assigned WPQ1 and the ListFormWebPart is assigned WPQ2.

Some of our JavaScript code is breaking because of the different WPQ numbers (1 vs 2, etc.)

We have tried to change the WPQ numbers through changing the Edit and Display aspx pages. We tried creating new aspx page with different web part ordering.

Question: Is there a way to change a WPQ number (exp. from WPQ1 to WPQ2, etc.)? Or, can you suggest a resource where we can find the solution?